# How to change dynamically rendered image when clicked in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array. ['Finance', 'Analytical Skills', 'leadership']. I'm rendering it using map function. Along with a react stepper component inside the map function. So it the stepper function renders with it as many time as the map renders. I want to change the image of the stepper function when I click it. ATM it is only changing the image of the firstly rendered box having a 'finance' and a stepper.

```
const ChangeIcon = (e) => {
    var myImg = document.getElementById(e.target.id) as HTMLImageElement;
    console.log("myimg", myImg);
    myImg.setAttribute("src", Levelfirt);
    console.log("value", e.target.id);
    setSelectedValue(e.target.alt);
    // setLevelOne(true)
}
```

```
<div className="competency-level-externally">
    {compArr.map((comp, compIndex) => {
        levelOneId = `levelOne-${compIndex + "-" + comp}`;
        levelTwoId = `levelTwo-${compIndex + "-" + comp}`;
        levelThreeId = `levelThree-${compIndex + "-" + comp}`;

        return (
            <div key={compIndex} className="comp-cont-externally">
                <p className="competency-text">{comp}</p>
                <div className="react-step">
                    <ProgressBar
                        percent={(props.step + 1) * 25}
                        filledBackground="black"
                        height="10px">
                        <button
                            style={{
                                border: "none",
                                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                marginTop: "-4rem",
                            }}
                            id={levelOneId}>
                            <Step transition="scale">
                                {({ accomplished, index }) => (
                                    <div
                                        style={{
                                            backgroundColor: `${
                                                accomplished ? "oranged" : null
                                            }`,
                                        }}
                                        className={`step ${
                                            accomplished ? "completed" : null
                                        }`}>
                                        **
                                        <div id="btn">
                                            <img
                                                onClick={(e) => ChangeIcon(e)}
                                                src={InitialLevelOne}
                                                style={{ height: "55px" }}
                                                id={levelOneId}
                                                alt="1"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        **
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </Step>
                        </button>
                        <button
                            style={{
                                border: "none",
                                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                marginTop: "-4rem",
                            }}
                            id={levelTwoId}>
                            <Step transition="scale">
                                {({ accomplished, index }) => (
                                    <div
                                        style={{
                                            backgroundColor: `${
                                                accomplished ? "oranged" : null
                                            }`,
                                        }}
                                        className={`step ${
                                            accomplished ? "completed" : null
                                        }`}>
                                        <div id="btn">
                                            <img
                                                onClick={(e) =>
                                                    ChangeIconLevelTwo(e)
                                                }
                                                src={InitialLevelTwo}
                                                style={{ height: "55px" }}
                                                id={levelTwoId}
                                                alt="2"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </Step>
                        </button>
                        <button
                            style={{
                                border: "none",
                                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                marginTop: "-4rem",
                            }}
                            id={levelThreeId}>
                            <Step transition="scale">
                                {({ accomplished, index }) => (
                                    <div
                                        style={{
                                            backgroundColor: `${
                                                accomplished ? "oranged" : null
                                            }`,
                                        }}
                                        className={`step ${
                                            accomplished ? "completed" : null
                                        }`}>
                                        <div>
                                            <img
                                                onClick={(e) =>
                                                    ChangeIconLevelThree(e)
                                                }
                                                id={levelThreeId}
                                                src={InitialLevelThree}
                                                style={{ height: "55px" }}
                                                alt="3"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </Step>
                        </button>
                    </ProgressBar>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think getting Element By Id is the reactive way to do that. can you explain to me why you don't just create a state and pass it to your image as src?

Comment: u can't use render metod into a map() call. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/ here u can finde the correct way